# How to make equal sign with circles, similar to \risingdotseq?

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

I'm looking for the best way to create the symbol very similar to `\risingdotseq`, just with circles instead of dots. Unfortunately, it looks like it's not in the standard set of symbols. Any help finding/creating it would be greatly appreciated.

[image: equal sign with rising circles]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. There is a symbol `\fallingdotseq` but with the dots instead of the circles. Using a mirror (command `\reflectbox`) you can obtained your symbol but with the dots.

Comment: Yes, but I need circles, not dots.

Comment: I think that this symbol not exist and it is important to built it.

Comment: What is the intended meaning?  Is it to be used in contrast to, e.g., `\fallingdotseq`?  Have you seen it in any other document?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: it's the symbol we use for Laplace transform.

Comment: @wutek -- Thank you.  Have you seen it in a published journal, or in an article posted on arXiv?  If so, I still have connections in the Unicode Technical Committee, and with solid documentation can submit it for inclusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a not-so-simple™ solution:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pict2e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\raisingcircleseq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\raising@circles@eq\relax}}
\newcommand{\raising@circles@eq}[2]{%
  \vphantom{#1+}%
  \vbox{
    \settowidth\unitlength{$#1\mspace{2mu}$}%
    \offinterlineskip\m@th
    \ialign{##\cr
      \hfil\small@circle{#1}$#1\mspace{1.5mu}$\cr\noalign{\vskip0.5\unitlength}
      $#1=$\cr\noalign{\post@vskip{+}{#1}}
      $#1\mspace{1.5mu}$\small@circle{#1}\hfill\cr\noalign{\post@vskip{-}{#1}}
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\small@circle}[1]{%
  \smash{%
    \begin{picture}(1,1)
    \small@linethickness{#1}
    \put(0.5,0.5){\circle{1}}
    \end{picture}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\small@linethickness}[1]{%
  \linethickness{%
      \ifx#1\displaystyle 0.8\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\textstyle 0.8\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle0.8\fontdimen8\scriptfont3\else
      1\fontdimen8\scriptscriptfont3\fi\fi\fi
  }%
}
\newcommand{\post@vskip}[2]{%
  \expandafter\vskip\expanded{%
    #1\ifx#2\scriptscriptstyle0.9\else\ifx#2\scriptstyle0.6\else0.3\fi\fi\unitlength
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a=\raisingcircleseq b$

$a\raisingcircleseq b$

${=\raisingcircleseq}{\scriptstyle=\raisingcircleseq}{\scriptscriptstyle=\raisingcircleseq}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's an option.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength{\circheight}
\settoheight{\circheight}{\(=\)}
\addtolength{\circheight}{.5pt}
\newcommand*{\smallcirc}{\scalebox{.51}{\(\scriptscriptstyle\boldsymbol{\circ}\)}}
\newcommand*{\risingcircleseq}{%
    \mathrel{%
        \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-.5pt}{\smallcirc}}%
        \mbox{=}%
        \makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{\circheight}[0pt]{\smallcirc}}%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\(A \risingcircleseq B\)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Works in all math styles.  Uses `stackengine` to build the macro and `scalerel` for automatic handling of math style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,scalerel}
\newcommand\eqdots{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{\ThisStyle{%
  \stackengine{-.5\LMpt}{\stackengine{.5\LMpt}{\SavedStyle=}%
  {\SavedStyle\scaleobj{.33}{\circ\,}}{O}{r}{F}{T}{S}}%
  {\SavedStyle\scaleobj{.33}{\,\circ}}{U}{l}{F}{T}{S}}}}}
\begin{document} 
$x\eqdots y$\par
$\scriptstyle x\eqdots y$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle x\eqdots y$\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution (in display style) with `\makebox` and  `accents`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makebox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\risingcirceq}{\mathrel{%
\underaccent{\raisebox{-0.5ex}[0pt]{\makebox[\widthof{$=$}][l]{\scalebox{0.6}{$\circ$}}}}{%
\accentset{\raisebox{-0.15ex}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[\widthof{$=$}][r]{\scalebox{0.6}{$\circ$}}}}{=}}
}}%

\begin{document}

    \[ a\risingcirceq b\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]